# dotnet.exe vs w3wp.exe: what's difference?

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, .net-core, access-violation

I saw apps hosted as `dotnet.exe` while my app with simple

```
       WebHost
              .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
              .UseConfiguration(config)
            //.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())

            .UseEnvironment(environment)

            //.UseIIS() //even commented those; still no effort
            //.UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
```

runs as `w3wp.exe`.
What's the difference and how to switch? I'm asking of it because `dotnet.exe`-hosted app runs well with big amount of data (>5GB) while same my with `w3wp.exe` fails on 2.6GB with `AccessViolation`.

Update: my app runs on unmanaged pool while dotnet.exe-based uses `.NET 4`.

Answer (score 5):

What you're really talking about is kind of two different things. First, you have the concept of running with a web server like IIS versus running via Kestrel directly. Then, there's the concept of running in IIS as in proc or out of proc.

Let's take the first. Any time you run anything in IIS, you get the w3wp.exe process (or multiple if running via web farm). That really has nothing to do with .NET Core, it's just the process for the App Pool in IIS. You can also choose to just run your app directly with `dotnet.exe` (Kestrel), which of course causes that process to be running.

Then, should you host in IIS, you can run in proc or out. With out of process, the former default (actually the former only way), IIS serves as a reverse proxy - the App Pool (w3wp.exe) proxies requests to the actual application process running via Kestrel (dotnet.exe). In that scenario, you have both processes present, because both are being used. ASP.NET Core 2.2 introduced a new hosting model: in process, where the ASP.NET Core app runs directly in the App Pool, result in just w3wp.exe.

Long and short, the presence, or lack thereof, of these processes depends on what you're doing. If you're using IIS in any shape or form, w3wp.exe is unavoidable.

*FWIW, "w3wp" is an acryonym for "World Wide Web Worker Process". That likely makes it a bit more obvious why it's omnipresent in IIS hosting scenarios: it's literally the worker process than handles web requests.*

As for your more specific issue, which essentially boils down to running out of memory, that really has nothing to do with anything other than how memory is being allocated. A 2.6GB threshold screams 32-bit: there's a max allocation of 4GB, and some amount of that is devoted to process overhead. However, there's no reason you should have to be running 32-bit. If your App Pool is running 64-bit, you can theoretically access more memory than you'd ever actually need. In short, there's nothing inherent to IIS or the w3wp.exe process that locks you in to only 2.6GB of allocatable memory. There must be something else at play.

Answer (score 0):

`dotnet.exe` says that it's hosted on default `Kestrel` web server and not IIS `w3wp.exe`. `Kestrel` is the default hosting environment (internal hosting). Check your `LaunchSetting.json` file and mostly you have configured IIS to be uses for hosting your application

Answer (score 0):

**dotnet.exe** is the worker process name of kestrel server. It is an internal web server that is included in .netcoreweb application by default. When .netcore application is running on the kertrel server then dotnet.exe process the incoming request.

**w3wp.ex** is the worker process name of IIS web server.When application is running on the IIS server then w3wp.exe process the incoming request.